# MySQL - Truncating Date/Time and Subtracting from Each Other

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which subtracts the original purchase time from the expires time to come up with a number of days:

```
select date(expires_dtime) - date(original_purchase_dtime)
from sl_player_subscription
where player_uuid = '9c61411c-54b4-45bd-8d07-264b1c2e4249'
```

`player_uuid that = '9c61411c-54b4-45bd-8d07-264b1c2e4249'` has an original purchase time of `2013-03-06 11:36:46` and an expire time of `2013-04-05 12:36:46.`

I want the output to read "30" which is the number of days between the purchase time and the expire time, but instead the output is 99. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try `DATEDIFF` function? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: I did now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2013-04-05 12:36:46', '2013-03-06 11:36:46')
```

**Result**

```
30
```

Using your columns:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(expires_dtime, original_purchase_dtime)
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/8497)

> `DATEDIFF()` returns ***expr1 – expr2*** expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. ***expr1*** and ***expr2*** are date or date-and-time expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation.

[Documentation: Date and Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)